# A Hero widget cannot be the descendant of another Hero widget after version change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I was recently trying to add in firebase fcm and it didn't work just caused several errors, so I rolled everything back to the original RUNNING code but upgraded flutter in the process...Since v1.3.10 a Hero cannot contain another Hero widget in its children hierarchy but I cannot find a fix. (ideally don't want to change version back)

I've checked the heroTags and also can't find any nested Hero widgets - maybe it is because of the animated builder?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' show radians, Vector3;
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import './Custom Icons/my_flutter_app_icons.dart' as CustomIcons;
import 'package:startoversword/liftPage.dart';
import 'package:startoversword/analWinkPage.dart';
import 'package:startoversword/lipPage.dart';
import 'package:startoversword/windscreenWiperPage.dart';
import 'package:startoversword/highHeelPage.dart';
import 'package:startoversword/rollerCoasterPage.dart';
import 'package:startoversword/notificationPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Menu',
      home: _placeMyAppScaffold(),
    );
  }
}

class _placeMyAppScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  Color defaultPink = Colors.white;
  Color pageThemeColor = Color(0xffF599E9);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox.expand(child: RadialMenu()),
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.white, size: 50.0),
              onPressed: () {
                print("notification pressed");
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => NotificationPage()));
              },
            ),
          ],
          title: Text('The S Word'),
          backgroundColor: pageThemeColor,
        ));
  }
}

class RadialMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _RadialMenuState();
}

class _RadialMenuState extends State<RadialMenu>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 900), vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadialAnimation(controller: controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class RadialAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  RadialAnimation({Key key, this.controller})
      : translation = Tween<double>(
          begin: 0.0,
          end: 100.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut),
        ),
        scale = Tween<double>(
          begin: 1.5,
          end: 0.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        ),
        rotation = Tween<double>(
          begin: 0.0,
          end: 360.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: Interval(
              0.0,
              0.7,
              curve: Curves.decelerate,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        super(key: key);

  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<double> rotation;
  final Animation<double> translation;
  final Animation<double> scale;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color defaultPink = Color(0xffF599E9);
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller,
        builder: (context, widget) {
          return Transform.rotate(
              angle: radians(rotation.value),
              child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: <Widget>[
                Hero(
                  tag: "liftScreenButton",
                  child: Container(
                    child: _buildButton(
                      30,
                      color: Color(0xfff665c6),
                      icon: CustomIcons.YoniFonts.lift,
                      context: context,
                      nextScreen: 'LiftScreen',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Hero(
                  tag: "winkScreenButton",
                  child: Container(
                    child: _buildButton(
                      90,
                      color: Color(0xffe654be),
                      icon: CustomIcons.YoniFonts.dot_circled,
                      context: context,
                      nextScreen: 'winkScreen',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Hero(
                  tag: "lipScreenButton",
                  child: Container(
                    child: _buildButton(
                      150,
                      color: Color(0xffd643b7),
                      icon: CustomIcons.YoniFonts.lips,
                      context: context,
                      nextScreen: 'lipScreen',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Hero(
                  tag: "windscreenWiperScreenButton",
                  child: Container(
                    child: _buildButton(
                      210,
                      color: Color(0xffc632b0),
                      icon: CustomIcons.YoniFonts.car,
                      context: context,
                      nextScreen: 'WindscreenWiperScreen',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Hero(
                  tag: "highHeelScreenButton",
                  child: Container(
                    child: _buildButton(
                      270,
                      color: Color(0xffb621a9),
                      icon: CustomIcons.YoniFonts.high_heels,
                      context: context,
                      nextScreen: 'HighHeelScreen',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Hero(
                  tag: "rollerCoasterScreenButton",
                  child: Container(
                    child: _buildButton(
                      330,
                      color: Color(0xffa711a2),
                      icon: CustomIcons.YoniFonts.roller_coaster,
                      context: context,
                      nextScreen: 'rollerCoasterScreen',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.scale(
                  scale: scale.value - 1,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(CustomIcons.YoniFonts.upsideDownYoni),
                      heroTag: "upsideDownYoni",
                      onPressed: _close,
                      backgroundColor: defaultPink),
                ),
                Transform.scale(
                  scale: scale.value,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: "initalYoni",
                    child: Icon(CustomIcons.YoniFonts.yoni),
                    onPressed: _open,
                    backgroundColor: defaultPink,
                  ),
                )
              ]));
        });
  }

  _open() {
    controller.forward();
  }

  _close({context, String nextScreen}) {
    controller.reverse();
    if (nextScreen == 'LiftScreen') {
      print("NEXT SCREEN IS LIFTPAGE");
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LiftPage()));
    } else if (nextScreen == "winkScreen") {
      print("NEXT SCREEN IS WINKPAGE");
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WinkPage()));
    } else if (nextScreen == "lipScreen") {
      print("NEXT SCREEN IS LIP PAGE");
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LipPage()));
    } else if (nextScreen == "WindscreenWiperScreen") {
      print("NEXT SCREEN IS WINDSCREENWIPERPAGE");
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WindScreenWiperPage()));
    } else if (nextScreen == "HighHeelScreen") {
      print("NEXT SCREEN IS HIGHHEELPAGE");
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HighHeelPage()));
    } else if (nextScreen == "rollerCoasterScreen") {
      print("NEXT SCREEN IS ROLLERCOASTERPAGE");
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RollerCoasterPage()));
    } else {
      return;
    }
    ;
  }

  _buildButton(double angle,
      {Color color, IconData icon, context, String nextScreen}) {
    final double rad = radians(angle);
    return Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..translate(
              (translation.value) * cos(rad), (translation.value) * sin(rad)),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(icon),
            heroTag: nextScreen,
            backgroundColor: color,
            onPressed: () => _close(context: context, nextScreen: nextScreen),
            elevation: 0));
  }
}
```

The error message points to

```
_buildButton(double angle,
      {Color color, IconData icon, context, String nextScreen}) {
    final double rad = radians(angle);
    return Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..translate(
              (translation.value) * cos(rad), (translation.value) * sin(rad)),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(icon),
            heroTag: nextScreen, //error here
            backgroundColor: color,
            onPressed: () => _close(context: context, nextScreen: nextScreen),
            elevation: 0));
  }
}
```

For interest here is the complete output

```
I/flutter (20678): #431    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3911
I/flutter (20678): #432    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3093
I/flutter (20678): #433    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2896
I/flutter (20678): #434    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:940
I/flutter (20678): #435    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:911
I/flutter (20678): #436    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:857
I/flutter (20678): #437    BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2320
I/flutter (20678): #438    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:856
I/flutter (20678): #439    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:737
I/flutter (20678): #440    runApp 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:787
I/flutter (20678): #441    main 
package:startoversword/main.dart:21
I/flutter (20678): #452    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations (package:flutter/src/services/system_chrome.dart)
I/flutter (20678): #463    OptionalMethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
I/flutter (20678): #474    MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
I/flutter (20678): (elided 46 frames from class _AssertionError, package dart:async, and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter (20678):
I/flutter (20678): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20678): Another exception was thrown: A Hero widget cannot be the descendant of another Hero widget.
I/chatty  (20678): uid=10088(com.oxspines.talkingsword) 1.ui identical 3 lines
I/flutter (20678): Another exception was thrown: A Hero widget cannot be the descendant of another Hero widget.
I/OpenGLRenderer(20678): Davey! duration=865ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=76957734745126, Vsync=76957768078458, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=76957769369260, AnimationStart=76957769756360, PerformTraversalsStart=76957774959760, DrawStart=76957778308860, SyncQueued=76957778894960, SyncStart=76957788359860, IssueDrawCommandsStart=76957793180660, SwapBuffers=76957809783260, FrameCompleted=76958609467060, DequeueBufferDuration=116998000, QueueBufferDuration=12148000,
I/Choreographer(20678): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer(20678): Davey! duration=1061ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=76957801411790, Vsync=76958751411752, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=76958769243160, AnimationStart=76958772853660, PerformTraversalsStart=76958779455160, DrawStart=76958795072260, SyncQueued=76958796183260, SyncStart=76958889098460, IssueDrawCommandsStart=76958889855560, SwapBuffers=76958893194360, FrameCompleted=76958955694360, DequeueBufferDuration=35517000, QueueBufferDuration=4901000,
```

Answer (score 13):

Thats because the FloatingActionButton already has a Hero widget wrapping it (check its source code).
And in your code you are embedding the FAB inside ANOTHER Hero widget.

To fix it you can just set the "heroTag" property in you FAB to "null" OR remove the wrapping Hero widget around that FAB, leaving just the default one.

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution to this problem is use Stack and overlap those hero widgets, so the hero widget will not be a child of hero widget anymore, but keep in mind the tag of both the hero widgets should be different !
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

if your wrapping a FloatingButton **Widget** with the Hero widget then you get that error, because the `FloatingActionButton` has an inbuild **Hero widget wrapping** it with already a `tag`
so to solve this you have to set the **Hero tag** for the FloatingActionButton to `null` so that your `tag` can override it check below for example:

```
Hero(
    tag: 'myTag',
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: null,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  )
```